# Retrieving rows with one entry in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (orders) where there are many sales orders and many customers, often many orders for the same customer. But I’m trying to find those orders that are for a single customer, and I don’t want to see the orders where there are multiple orders for the same customer. My example might help.

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╗
║ Customer ║ Order Number ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╣
║   ABC    ║     123      ║
║   ABC    ║     456      ║
║   XYZ    ║     789      ║
║   MNO    ║     987      ║
║   XYZ    ║     654      ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╝
```

So in the example, I only want to see Customer MNO and order number 987 as there is only one entry for that customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm, you can do this with aggregation:

```
select customer, min(OrderNumber) as OrderNumber
from t
group by customer
having count(*) = 1;
```

With only one row, the `min()` returns the order number on that row.

Another method is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.customer = t.customer and t2.OrderNumber <> t.OrderNumber
                 );
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to retrieve more columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below

```
with tbl (Customer,Order_Number) as
(select 'ABC',123 from dual union all
select 'ABC',456 from dual union all
select 'XYZ',789 from dual union all
select 'MNO',987 from dual union all
select 'XYZ',654 from dual)
 --recreating the source table
select customer,Order_Number from (
select t.*, count(customer) over (partition by customer) as cnt from tbl t)
where cnt =1
```